# How to use for loop to print values from array in mpdf PHP

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am using MPDF Library to generate pdf file form database .

i want to show whatsapp number from database in html table TD using array with for loop in MPDF.

here is my code which i try but it cannot print any value .

please help me out to figure out the problem and able to show records using for loop

```
       $query = "SELECT * from  social_messaging_app  where User_Id = '$split_ids[0]' and Request_Id='$split_ids[1]'  and Social_Messaging_App_Name LIKE 'Wh%' ORDER BY Social_Messaging_App_Id DESC";

                            $res_cus = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                            $total_rec_whatsaap = mysqli_num_rows($res_cus);
                            $whatsapp_accounts = array();
                            $whatsapp_id = 1;
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_cus)) {
                                $whatsapp_accounts[$whatsapp_id] = $row['Social_Messaging_App_No'];
                                $whatsapp_id++;

                            }
        $html="";
        if($total_rec_whatsaap>0){
    $html .= ' 
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>

                            <td style="width: 5%;font-size:14px;"></td>
                            <td style="width: 25%;font-size:14px;">Whatsapp Address(es)</td>
                        <td style="width: 70%; border-bottom: 1px solid black;text-align: left;font-size:14px;">';
                                    for($i = 1; $i <= $total_rec_whatsaap; $i++)
                                    {

                                     strtoupper($whatsapp_accounts[$i]);
                                    }

     $html .= '      
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                    </tbody>
                </table> ';
}
```

Please assist me to print values in td. using below code it give me empty row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed concatenating the string in `for` loop

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_rec_whatsaap; $i++)
{
      $html .= strtoupper($whatsapp_accounts[$i]);
}
```